# Sum items where a specific ID - Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

Extremely new here (please be gentle).

I am trying to get a calculation to work on a report which looks at a table within my dataset and will sum up all fields which have a specific ID.

I have managed to get a table working which displays all my items but then separately I just wanted have underneath a few stats, so percentage of people going into volunteering etc so was adding them as a separate calculated field so as to use some formulas.

I thought the simplest way (and it seems I was wrong) was:

```
=iif(Fields!Kpiid.Value=1,SUM(Fields!TotalTarget.Value),0)
```

All information is in the same table and each entity has up to 13 KPIids.

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated and here is a [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8556E93A9BB45E00!127679&authkey=!AJs0cDXerKU4zOk&ithint=file%2Cxls) to the finished document so you can see what I was trying to achieve at the bottom (its in Excel).

Comment: Have you tried putting the IIF inside the SUM, so that the SUM either uses the field's value or 0 for that row?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a SUM CASE?

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN KpID = 1 THEN TotalTarget.Value ELSE END) 
SUM(CASE WHEN KpID = X THEN TotalTarget.Value ELSE END) 

FROM Table
```

Comment: Where would I put SUM CASE in Report Builder. I'm trying to add it as a Calc field.

Comment: My apologies , I thought this was sql server tag.